# How to get the updated customer record in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, collection, customer-address

I am trying to fetch the customer record which is updated. Customer update implies both customer entity as well as customer's address.

I am relying on the updated_at column which technically says that this record has been updated. I am trying with below approach:-

1. Get the customer collection.
   $collection
2. Add filter on updated_at
   $collection->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['gt' => $startTime]);
   $collection->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['lt' => $endTime]);

This gives me the below query:-

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`website_id` = '1') AND (`e`.`updated_at` > '2021-07-14T08:45:06Z[UTC]') AND (`e`.`updated_at` < '2021-07-16T08:13:00.129Z[UTC]') LIMIT 4
```

This gives us only customer data.

However, I want a query like the below:-

```
SELECT c.* FROM magento.customer_entity as c inner join magento.customer_address_entity as a on c.default_billing=a.entity_id WHERE (`c`.`website_id` = '1') AND ((`c`.`updated_at` > '2021-07-14T08:45:06Z[UTC]') AND (`c`.`updated_at` < '2021-07-16T08:13:00.129Z[UTC]'))  or ((`a`.`updated_at` > '2021-07-14T08:45:06Z[UTC]') AND (`a`.`updated_at` < '2021-07-16T08:13:00.129Z[UTC]'))  LIMIT 4
```

How to approach this? I am a new Magento extension developer.

Comment: can you specify your requirement in more details with why you needed address information here?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, I don't need address here. What i am saying that i want to fetch those customer record (customer_entity table) whose address has been changed. If we see address is stored in customer_address_entity table, When we change the customer address then its customer_address_entity table which gets updated (updated_at column in table). In this case we have to join these tables to get the customer_entity data right ?